# Why do we need to call "disposeBy(bag)" explicitly after "subscribe" in RxSwift

Tags: rx-swift

I read about this from a blog post http://adamborek.com/memory-managment-rxswift/:

> When you subscribe for an `Observable` the `Disposable` keeps a reference to the `Observable` and the `Observable` keeps a strong reference to the `Disposable` (Rx creates some kind of a retain cycle here). Thanks to that if user navigates back in navigation stack the `Observable` won’t be deallocated unless you want it to be deallocated.

So purely just for understanding this, I created this dummy project: where is there a view, and in the middle of the view, there is a giant button which will emit events about how many times the button is tapped on. Simple as that.

```
import UIKit
import RxCocoa
import RxSwift

class Button: UIButton {
    private var number: Int = 0

    private let buttonPushedSubject: PublishSubject<Int> = PublishSubject.init()
    var buttonPushedObservable: Observable<Int> { return buttonPushedSubject }

    deinit {
        print("Button was deallocated.")
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc final func buttonTapped() {
        number = number + 1
        buttonPushedSubject.onNext(number)
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet private weak var button: Button!

    deinit {
        print("ViewController was deallocated.")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        button.buttonPushedObservable.subscribe(onNext: { (number) in
            print("Number is \(number)")
        }, onError: nil, onCompleted: nil, onDisposed: nil)
    }
}
```

And surprisingly, after I close this view controller, the logs look like this:

```
Number is 1
Number is 2
Number is 3
Number is 4
ViewController was deallocated.
Button was deallocated.
...
```

which means both `ViewController` and the `Button` have been released! In this case, I didn't call the `disposeBy(bag)` and the compiler giving warning.

[image]

Then I started looking at the implementation of `subscribe(onNext:...)` (c/p below):

```
let disposable: Disposable

if let disposed = onDisposed {
    disposable = Disposables.create(with: disposed)
}
else {
    disposable = Disposables.create()
}

let callStack = Hooks.recordCallStackOnError ? Hooks.customCaptureSubscriptionCallstack() : []

let observer = AnonymousObserver<E> { event in

    switch event {
    case .next(let value):
        onNext?(value)
    case .error(let error):
        if let onError = onError {
            onError(error)
        }
        else {
            Hooks.defaultErrorHandler(callStack, error)
        }
        disposable.dispose()
    case .completed:
        onCompleted?()
        disposable.dispose()
    }
}
return Disposables.create(
    self.asObservable().subscribe(observer),
    disposable
)
```

In this block of code above, it is true that `observer` holds a strong reference to `disposable` through the lambda function. However, what I don't understand is that how does `disposable` holds a strong reference to `observer`?

Answer (score 2):

While the observable is active there is a reference cycle, but the deallocation of your button sends a complete event which breaks the cycle.

That said, if you do something like this `Observable<Int>.interval(3).subscribe()` the stream will not deallocate.

Streams only shutdown (and thus deallocate) if the source completes/errors or if dispose() is called on the resulting disposable. With the above line of code, the source (`interval`) will never complete or error and no reference to the disposable was kept so there is no way to call dispose() on it.

The best way to think of it is this... `complete`/`error` is the source's way of telling the sink that it is done emitting (which means the stream is no longer needed,) and calling `dispose()` on the disposable is the sinks way of telling the source that it isn't interested in receiving any more events (which also means the stream is no longer needed.) In order to deallocate the stream, either the source or sink needs to report that it's finished.

To explicitly answer your question... You don't *need* to add the disposable to a dispose bag, but if the view controller deletes without disposing and the source doesn't send a complete message, the stream will leak. So safety first, make sure the sink disposes when it's done with the stream.

Comment: Thanks for the example of the infinite stream. However, for "the deallocation of your button sends a complete event which breaks the cycle", I didn't call `buttonPushedSubject.onCompleted()` explicitly, does that mean that the stream is leaking in this case too?

Comment: Yes. I thought you were using `.rx.tap` to make your observable. It will send a `complete` when the button is deallocated.

Comment: Do you know how/where it is leaking? I don't see any code that results in a retain cycle and trying to understand. I also tried using the memory cycle detector in Xcode and cannot find anything.